# How to blanket change 1000's of 301's to 404's in Joomla?

Tags: http-status-code-404, redirect, joomla3.0, http-status-code-301

I recently migrated an old Wordpress site over to Joomla and it has created an obscene amount of 301's in the Redirects component and I would like to change these to 404's as 99% of them have no relevance anymore (its as if anything and everything from the last site was indexed!). Does anyone know of a way to do this without having to trawl through 5400 of them..?

Comment: Please take a look on this tutorial [link](https://joomlaseo.com/checklist/reroute-non-existing-url-s-with-301-redirects). For url redirects you can also use the build in joomla components: [link](https://extensions.joomla.org/category/site-management/url-redirection).Make sure that first you have to apply any major changes on test site(i.e, make the live copy and test it then deploy to live), because its always good practice.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look on this tutorial `https://joomlaseo.com/checklist/reroute-non-existing-url-s-with-301-redirects`. For url redirects you can also use the build in joomla components: [link](https://extensions.joomla.org/category/site-management/url-redirection). Make sure that first you have to apply any major changes on test site(i.e, make the live copy and test it then deploy to live), because its always good practice.

Thanks & Regards,
Kaif